# ui:repeatn tag inside ui:repeat..not working

Tags: icefaces

I am using ice:faces in my project.
I have issues with UI:Repeat.
It never works ....

ui:repeatn tag inside ui:repeat..

do I need to do anything different..

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

<ui:repeat value="#{item.rowField3}" var="section">
<ice:panelGrid columns="#{section.columns}">
<ui:repeat items="#{section.fieldInfo}" var="fieldInfo">
<ui:include src="rowField.jspx" />
</ui:repeat>
</ice:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute "items" in your nested ui:repeat should be "value".